# Laravel Query Builder left join

Tags: laravel, query-builder

can someone please tell me, why i am not able to select section from sections table using left join. i want list of teachers in a table, i am able to access all data from teachers table, but i am not able to see sections using left join. 
Teacher Table have  section_id column, which should access data from sections table on section column.

right now it is giving error when i try to fetch data in view using {{$teacher->section}} Below is my code.

```
public function listteachers(Request $request)
{
  $teachers = DB::table('teachers')
  ->select('teachers.*')
  ->leftjoin('sections', 'teachers.section_id', '=', 'sections.id')
  ->orderBy('pass_exp', 'ASC')
  ->get();
return view('teachers.list',compact('teachers'));
}
```

Comment: `->leftJoin()` instead of `->leftjoin()`?

Comment: same error: Undefined property: stdClass::$section

Comment: i guess you are not selecting sections. Just try removing  `->select('teachers.*')` this line

Comment: @vijaykumar Missing required parameters for [Route: teachers.edit]

Comment: Now, it is an other issue. `edit` routes need an ID as a parameter. The error comes from your view I guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to select the columns you want from the sections table in your query.

For example:

```php
$teachers = DB::table('teachers')
    ->select('teachers.*', DB::raw('sections.name as section_name'))
    ->leftJoin('sections', 'teachers.section_id', '=', 'sections.id')
    ->orderBy('pass_exp', 'ASC')
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the code to the following

```
  $teachers = DB::table('teachers')
        ->select('teachers.*','sections.name as section_name')
        ->leftJoin('sections', 'teachers.section_id', '=', 'sections.id')
        ->orderBy('pass_exp', 'ASC')
       ->get();
```